# IIS 7 Integrated handler does not match when path does not exist

Tags: .net, http-status-code-404, httphandler, integrated-pipeline-mode

I'm upgrading from classic to integrated. I upgraded my web.config handlers to the new sections. However nothing worked, so I started a bran new MVC 4 project, created a handler, registered it in the web.config and it never fires if the path doesn't exist.

This handler takes the url, finds a different file, and writes that file to the output stream along with custom headers.

For example I am trying to do:

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
<clear/>
<add name="GifHandler" path="*.gif" verb="*" type="MyType, MyAssembly" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

When I go to the handler directly, it's fine, when I go to IIS and look at registered handlers, it's there, but when I go to the url localhost/something.gif I get a 404.

I have a feeling IIS is checking if the file exists before handing it off.

So how do I get the handler to accept all gifs even if they don't exist?

Comment: When I go three directories deep, it works. So http://localhost/something.gif fails, but http://localhost/som/et/hing.gif

Comment: Was an issue with MVC... apparently you have to register the route.